# Python Exception No Details

Tags: python-3.x, speech-recognition

I am reading a WAV file using following code

```
from glob import glob
import os
from datetime import datetime
import speech_recognition as sr

r = sr.Recognizer()

start_time = datetime.now()
print("Start Time : " + str(start_time))

text=""
count= 0
for f in glob('audio_*'):
    print(f)
    with sr.AudioFile(f) as source:
        audio = r.record(source)
        try:
           s = r.recognize_google(audio)
           text=text+s
        except Exception as e:
             print("Exception: "+str(e))
            
        count=count+1
        if count > 10 :
           break

end_time = datetime.now()
print("End Time : " + str(end_time))
print('Duration: {}'.format(end_time - start_time) + " For File Lenth of :" + str(len))

print(text.capitalized())
```

But when I execute the code it is randomly giving me following error

```
(transcript) c:\temp\transcript>python read.py
Start Time : 2021-02-07 00:33:13.137851
audio_10001.wav
audio_10002.wav
audio_10003.wav
**Exception**:
audio_10004.wav
audio_10005.wav
audio_10006.wav
audio_10007.wav
audio_10008.wav
**Exception**:
audio_10009.wav
```

Can you pl help me out why it is giving me an exception and without any details ? This wav files split over 4 mins duration

Thanks

Comment: Why not just raise the exception instead of printing it? Maybe this will give you more information, especially regarding the exception type. Either remove `try: ... except` or put `raise e` after the `print(...)`

Comment: In the last line of this documentation (https://github.com/Uberi/speech_recognition/blob/master/reference/library-reference.rst#recognizer_instancerecognize_googleaudio_data-audiodata-key-unionstr-none--none-language-str--en-us--pfilter-union0-1-show_all-bool--false---unionstr-dictstr-any), it says that there are two types of exceptions: `speech_recognition.UnknownValueError ` and `speech_recognition.RequestError`. I don't see that you added a Google Speech Recognition API key. Maybe that is the issue you are having here.

Comment: @Jonas thanks it is giving me if not isinstance(actual_result, dict) or len(actual_result.get("alternative", [])) == 0: raise UnknownValueError()
speech_recognition.UnknownValueError

Comment: @Jonas on Google API I could not find out speech recognition it is only showing Cloud Speech-to-Text API Will you pl guide and help me ? Thanks

Comment: @Jonas why it is giving speech_recognition.UnknownValueError ?

Comment: Any updates to resolve this issue ? Thanks

Comment: According to the documentation: Raises a `speech_recognition.UnknownValueError` exception if the speech is unintelligible. So Google seems to be unable to identify the speech. You can write `except sr.UnknownValueError: print("Failed to recognize speech") to give some more readable feedback.

Comment: As for the API Key, to be honest I have no idea. I never actually worked with `speech_recognition` before. Maybe try this: https://cloud.google.com/speech-to-text/docs/quickstart-client-libraries#client-libraries-install-python